# Use emacs syntax coloring when not in emacs

Tags: terminal-emacs

Emacs in -nw mode colors source code files, in this screenshot you see how emacs colors the .rb file I opened.
Over the weeks/months I've gotten used to the coloring.

Despite how hard I try, there always comes a time when I'm
not in emacs, and I'm doing a `cat` in the Terminal.app bash shell.
So much like you can pipe a compact block of json to get nicely
indented json, is it possible to pipe a .rb file to some scripts that runs Emacs and extracts the syntax coloring that Emacs uses?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify how this is relevant to Emacs.  I guess what you're really asking is "how to use Emacs in a pipe to color my file".  If so, please says it.

Comment: Yes, translate Emacs font-lock faces into ANSI escape code, see https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi

Comment: You can install/use the package ```highlight``` from homebrew  - see discussion on this page: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267361/syntax-highlighting-in-the-terminal#267362 - this package support colour customisation.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is put on hold -- I've voted for it to be reopened. Anyway, I asked myself the same thing a couple of years ago -- when I didn't find any package I wrote my own (https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi as @ xuchunyang already posted). Any text Emacs can highlight, it can render using ANSI sequences so it can be viewed in a terminal, using the command `e2ansi-cat`. It integrates with pagers like `more`and `less` so anything you view with them becomes highlighted automatically.

Comment: really don't understand why this question is closed

Comment: @xuchunyang can you post your suggestion as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the syntax coloring outside Emacs, two working examples are [htmlize](https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize) for the web and [e2ansi](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi) for the terminal. For your need, you can use `e2ansi-cat` provided by e2ansi, here is a screenshot of it:

[image: screenshot of cat and e2ansi-cat]

By the way, if you use Eshell, you can easily get the syntax coloring:

```el
(defun eshell/cat-with-syntax-highlight (filename)
  (let ((existing-buffer (get-file-buffer filename))
        (buffer (find-file-noselect filename)))
    (eshell-print
     (with-current-buffer buffer
       (font-lock-ensure)
       (buffer-string)))
    (unless existing-buffer
      (kill-buffer buffer))
    nil))
```

[image: screenshot of cat-with-syntax-highlight]